# android robolectric : mocking HTTP Requests - cannot find class Http

Tags: android, maven, robolectric

This is probably a stupid question; however, I am out of options and would appreciate help. I am trying to mock file downloads using Robolectric. I am referring to the class [HttpTest.java](https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/pivotallabs/api/HttpTest.java), and the Robolectric [blog post](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-test-http-requests.html).

My problem: Maven is unable to find the Http class referred to in the HttpTest.java code. I could manually bring it over as a class in the same package, but I ended up getting a NullPtrException in one of the methods of class Http.

I have searched on the net for a solution. I have also verified the modules configuration in the pom file. I do have com.pivotlabs present there.

Has anyone gotten this working? Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you post the complete exception stack trace?

Comment: It might not be of help because Maven simply cannot find the class Http. I know it belongs to com.pivotlabs.api; but Maven should find it on its own for things to work. I have the artifact 'robolectric' as dependency in my pom.xml.

Comment: I am trying to run tests from command line - mvn clean test. I need Http.java from src/main/java. src/test/java contains the HttpTest class. I can successfully run the tests on the sample project. I have copied the same dependencies in my pom file now, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working.

1. Http is a class internal to Robolectric's sample code. It can be used outside; but you might not want to do that if your code is gonna be built non-locally.
2. The clarification/mention in documentation that would have gone long way in helping me is: "Robolectric will give you the response you create using addPendingHttpResponse() for your HTTP request, no matter how you do the request. Robolectric will NOT do an actual HTTP request." Once I understood this, rest was easy.
3. I used Apache's DefaultHttpClient for my request, and verified received response against the already created response.

Hope this helps; I'd be happy to clarify further.

Thanks for the help I received here.

[I had asked this question on Robolectric's google group as well.]